# Запуск окна wxWidgets в DLL с потока

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "MainWindow.h"

static wxAppConsole *wxCreateApp()
{
    wxAppConsole::CheckBuildOptions(WX_BUILD_OPTIONS_SIGNATURE, "my app");
    return new MainWindow();
}

// The only public function, declared also in library's header.
void RunApp()
{
    wxApp::SetInitializerFunction(wxCreateApp);
    wxEntry(0, NULL);
}
extern "C" XI_EXPORT bool run(const char* context)
{
    RunApp();
    return true;
}

extern "C" XI_EXPORT bool stop(const char* context)
{
    return true;
}

#ifdef XI_WIN

#include <windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hmodule, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    switch (reason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
#endif // XI_WIN
```

Как осуществить запуск окна с нового потока?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен + отформатируйте код, убрав лишние пробельные символы.

Comment: Запуск окна с не главного потока

Comment: Попробуйте на основном SO спросить, здесь этот тег крайне малоактивен.